# Advanced Universal Remote or basic home automation

Tags: smart-home, android, infrared

I need an advice on sort of basic home automation. Let's say, I have 3 multimedia points in my home. 2 of them are TVs with attached recievers, players and game consoles, almost everything is network-attached. The other one is just a stereo reciever with a vynil turntable and RPi as a network audio player.

Right now everything is quite messy, because I need to use 3-5 input devices (remotes, gamepads etc) to operate just one point.

It would be cool to implement kind of Universal Remote thing which I would be able to use from my android phone or tablet, or from a laptop. I need some zone division of course. Also I would like to have layouts with some basic actions like Vol+, Vol- or PwrBtn, but also some chained actions, like "let's play a movie": turn on TV, switch to that input, turn on reciever, switch to that input, turn on player, start an android remote app for it etc.

Is there any platform on which it wouldn't be too painful to implement? As of hardware, I have a dedicated PC which I can use as a server, I have a couple of zmote remotes and a couple of Microsoft IR blasters/recievers. I'm an IT geek with moderate programming skills, so I'm not limited to just consumer only solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer myself. Home Assistant is just enough to implement almost anything I've wanted. I've tried OpenHAB and it was waaaay too long until I was able to automate anything. Also I got really confused with it's Dashboards, doesn't look like an easy to enter solution.

On the other hand, I gave a shot to Home Assistant and within just a weekend I've already added all my devices I have and willing to automate. Dashboards are quite messy too, but not that hard to use. And I didn't had to write a line of python or whatever code, simple YAML configs at most.

Comment: Awesome that you came back to answer your question!  It would be even awesomer for future users if you could expand it a bit...  Although it isn't necessarily the case since you're answering you're own question, it looks a lot more like a comment than a full answer.  Anyhow thanks for letting us know what worked in the end!

Comment: I've edited the post and tried to be a little bit more specific

Comment: That's awesome!  Thanks so much.  Looks like a great answer now.